# mod_rewrite not working the same in HTTPS as HTTP

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

UPDATED:

I currently have a .htaccess file in a folder called /pages/ that contains the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../page_rewrite.php [L,QSA]
```

This then passes the path to page_rewrite.php when someone accesses www.something.com/pages/some/page-to-go/to/

This works perfectly when i access the site via

http://www.something.com/pages/some/page-to-go/to/

but i get a 403 when i go via https

https://www.something.com/pages/some/page-to-go/to/

accessing all php pages directly works just not the rewrittern URL.

Any ideas? i have been googling it but cant find what im looking for.

Comment: What's the code in page_rewrite.php that gets the path info look like?

Comment: It will still display a page even if there is no path info so like: http://www.something.com/pages/ so its not even getting that far

Comment: This is not a solution: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l will be always true, so you can delete them.